# Divide multiple route files in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How can I can divide a single route file into multiple route files in Flask?

I have a big **index.py** file and I need to divide it into multiple route files.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/

Comment: Alternatively, what is stopping you from dividing your code into many file, and simply importing the methods?